# Cannot install vuemdb

Tags: vue.js

I am following the [installation](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/vue/getting-started/installation/) guide with a just created vue application under advanced installation.

```
vue create project
# add router and select vue 3

cd project
vue add mdb
# selecting free version
# tried different configurations, always resulting in the following error
```

> npm ERR! code ETARGET
> npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for mdbvue@1.2.0.
> npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
> npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

Am I doing something wrong?

- @vue/cli 4.5.13
- npm version 7.20.3

On Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

mdb plugin name is mdb5: `vue add mdb5`